# Another React Native version mismatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting a React Native version mismatch.

```
JavaScript version: 0.51.0
Native version: 0.52.0
```

I know there are others who have posted similar online but I simply don't understand what I need to do to resolve it, and as I'm supposed to avoid asking for help in other posts I am starting a new one!

I've closed Terminals and run build again as suggested elsewhere, considered changing Expo versions but unsure if I need to, and how. Anyone got a simply-to-explain solution?

Which version of what do I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Generally this error occurs when the `packager` of the `previous app` is building the `next app`, which contains a different `react-native` version

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So should I be looking to change the native version back? Or something else?

Comment: Check your expo sdk version in the `package.json` file, the relevant solutions can be found [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/923)

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up changing the Expo version to 23.0.0 (was 25.0.0) using the upgrade info here https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v23-0-0-is-now-available-be0a8c655414 and that seems to have got rid of the mismatch issue. Got other issues now it seems, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The issue of mismatch is related to the changing of your react-native version without properly updating peer dependencies and native projects.

If your project is using Expo, try following the upgrade guidelines here offered from Facebook.

[Upgrading to new React Native versions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html)
Found under.. "Create React Native App projects"

The [document](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md) reference in will give you working mappings.

Once updated, run in your project root.

```
npm prune && npm install
# OR
yarn
```

Afterward start your app with your cache cleared.

```
npm start --reset-cache
# or
yarn start --reset-cache
```